# Google Account(and apps) not syncing on my Realme C2(Android 9)

Tags: sync, google-account, 9.0-pie, google-apps, realme

My google account and app data are not syncing on my Realme C2 (Android 9). The data of a few apps like Chrome and Calendar is syncing and showing up when I select my google account under "Accounts and Sync", but the data of other important apps like Gmail, Drive, and Keep is not syncing. The "Sync Now" button is unresponsive.  I tried removing and re-adding the google account, clearing the data and cache of all google apps, uninstalling and reinstalling them, and rebooting the device. But nothing seems to work. Please help me with this.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was lack of storage. The sync resumed when approximately 2 GB of storage space was available on my device.